# Delete some count of rows from csv file

Tags: php, csv

Example I have csv file with million rows and I created queue for habdle row by handle step 100 rows. And after 100 row wlll be handled I want to remove it from this csv file. It's possible ? Or maybe someone know another tools or way hoow to do that. Would be great if will be exist opportunity remove rows with offset and limit. And approach when we get all content from file then transform it ro array and execure array shift for remove first line example and then file put content again into the file not correct for this issue, because my csv file contain millions rows.
I use php and League\Csv library, but maybe there is another tool for this task?
Could possible delete some count of rows from csv file, just remove or replace to empty ?

Comment: I will try with ftell to get the pointer position in the file then call sed by shell_exec

Comment: @MelvynMarigny could you share example code ?